# Installing ffmpeg in mac os "command not found"

Tags: terminal, mac, homebrew

Hello I tried installing ffmpeg after installing homebrew. when I typed "brew install ffmpeg" it says "command not found" can you help please?[image: installed homebrew]

[image: error message "command not found"]

Comment: Instead of screenshots, please copy/paste directly from Terminal and apply "code" formatting. This makes the text appear in search results (and also helps people with screen readers).

Comment: While editing please also add the result of `echo $PATH` to the question.

Answer (score 5):

When you ran the first command, you pressed "any other key" than RETURN, and so you never actually installed homebrew.

Re-run the first command and make sure to hit the return (enter) key when asked.

Comment: Thank you soo much. you were right I didnt click enter. 
but now Its asking for a password. just wondering what password is it ?

Comment: Your own password for your user account.